# PostgreSQL: Distribute rows evenly and according to frequency

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have trouble with a complex ordering problem. I have following example data:

```
table "categories"
id | frequency
 1 |     0
 2 |     4
 3 |     0

table "entries"
id | category_id | type
 1 |       1     |   a
 2 |       1     |   a
 3 |       1     |   a
 4 |       2     |   b
 5 |       2     |   c
 6 |       3     |   d
```

I want to put `entries` rows in an order so that `category_id`,
and `type` are distributed evenly.

More precisely, I want to order `entries` in a way that:

1. `category_ids` that refer to a `category` that has `frequency`=0 are
   distributed evenly - so that a row is followed by a different `category_id`
   whenever possible. e.g. `category_ids` of rows: 1,2,1,3,1,2.
2. Rows with `category_ids` of `categories` with `frequency`<>0 should
   be inserted from ca. the beginning with a minimum of *frequency* rows between them
   (the gaps should vary). In my example these are rows with `category_id`=2.
   So the result could start with row id #1, then #4, then a minimum of 4 rows of other
   `categories`, then #5.
3. in the end result rows with same `type` should not be next to each other.

Example result:

```
id | category_id | type
 1 |       1     |   a
 4 |       2     |   b
 2 |       1     |   a
 6 |       3     |   d
 .. some other row ..
 .. some other row ..
 .. some other row ..
 5 |       2     |   c
```

`entries` are like a stream of things the user gets (one at a time).
The whole ordering should give users some variation. It's just there to not
present them similar entries all the time, so it doesn't have to be perfect.
The query also does not have to give the same result on each call - using
`random()` is totally fine.

`frequencies` are there to give `entries` of certain categories a higher
priority so that they are not distributed across the whole range, but are placed more
at the beginning of the result list. Even if there are a lot of these entries, they
should not completely crowd out the `frequency`=0 entries at the beginning, through.

I'm no sure how to start this. I think I can use window functions and
`ntile()` to distribute rows by `category_id` and `type`.
But I have no idea how to insert the non-0-category-entries afterwards.

Comment: If using `random` is fine, why don't you simple order by random values? E.g. `random() / (frequency  +1)` puts all high priority rows in the top 20 percent.

Comment: @dnoeth: Can you be more specific? I want the results to be like I specified above, so a simple ```ORDER BY random()``` won't work. I meant using a random function for inserting the non-0 ```frequencies``` (for example) would be possible.

Comment: @dnoeth That could work nicely for getting some category entries first (have to test that). But how would that work together with evenly distributing the 0-category entries (and types)? Or did you mean just using ```random()``` everywhere?